# Wordpress and phpbb3 SEO premod 3.0.12 installed in a subfolder (htaccess?)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, phpbb3

My wordpress website:

```
example.com
```

My phpbb 30 premod folder:

```
example.com/forum
```

When I go to `example.com/forum`, it works. But then I do: `example.com/forum/myrewriteurl-16.html` or `example.com/form/urlthatdoesnotexist`, then I go to the 404 wordpress page.

This in my .htaccess in wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
deny from 46.22.166.213
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**NOTE: The wordpress installation is under a subfolder too (i am working in shared hosting).**

Comment: So internal url of your forum not working , right?

Comment: You are right. THe internal url are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please do following :

1 - Revise your .htaccess as per below :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectoryinstallfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

**First try to do above 1st step and then if does not work then follow also below steps.**

2 - Go to your wordpress folder ,  copy [**Do not cut please**]index.php & .htaccess both files and paste them in /public_html

3 - Save permalink again for refresh and then try to access forum internal URLs.

Comment: But one thing. I am using shared hosting, and the wordpress is also in a subfolder.

Comment: Yes then revise .htaccess file as per my first step. Revise .htaccess which is in your wordpress folder.

Comment: But does "subdirectoryinstallfolder" is forum or the wordpress subdirectory installation folder?

Comment: Wordpress sub directory. It consider forum as sub directory of wordpress.

Comment: Sorry but it does not work. I added "RewriteBase /foro/" to my .htaccess localted in /public_html/mywordpressinstallation/ and it does not work. Then I do the same but with "RewriteBase /mywordpressinstallation/" and I obtain the same results.

Comment: please refer - There are many other solution available : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315947/wordpress-and-phpbb3-seo-premod-3-0-12-installed-in-a-subfolder-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution:

It is needed to go to the phpbb administration panel, then to go to the seo section, then htaccess section, the to copy the .htaccess shown, and then to paste the content **at the beginning** of the wordpress .htaccess file. In my case, .htaccess file located in /my-wordpress-installation/.

Answer (score 0):

The phpbb's .htaccess should be in the forums root directory. There are options in phpbb-seo ACP page to generate up a .htaccess to use.